# Return a vector of Grades from if-else statements

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement, for-loop

I have an if-else if construct which gives me grades A, B, C, D, F depending on marks from 0-100.

```
if (mark > 100) | (mark < 0)
disp('Invalid mark');
return; % Exit from the program.
end % Of first if statement
if mark >= 80 % Mark is in range 80 - 100.
grade = 'A';
elseif mark >= 70 % Mark is in range 70 - 79.
grade = 'B'; 
elseif mark >= 60 % Mark is in range 60 - 69.
grade = 'C';
elseif mark >= 50 % Mark is in range 50 - 59.
grade = 'D'  
else % Mark is in range 0 - 44.
grade = 'F';
end
disp(grade);
```

Now, I have a another long vector of numeric marks (from 0-100) of size Ax1 called 'marks'. I am not sure; how to input each of those numeric marks through this line of code to achieve an  output vector of grades?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a vectorized way, along these lines:

```
grade_names = 'FDCBA';
th = [50 60 70 80]; % thresholds that define the grades
marks = [75 70 33 99 88 58]; % data
grades_num = 1 + sum(bsxfun(@ge, marks(:).', th(:) ), 1); % vector with numbers
    %  indicating grade: 1 for the first ('F'), 2 for the second ('D') etc
grades = grade_names(grades_num);
```

In the example, this gives the char vector od grades

```
grades =
BBFAAD
```

---

If you prefer cell array output, change the first line to

```
grade_names = {'F' 'D' 'C' 'B' 'A'};
```

which will give

```
grades =
    'B'    'B'    'F'    'A'    'A'    'D'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`for i=1:length(marks)`
mark=marks(i);`

followed by your code
and adding an end in the end for the for loop.
You can also put the grades in a vector too and not just display them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution slightly different from [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) 's answer:

```
if numel(find((mark > 100) | (mark < 0))) > 0
    disp('Invalid mark');
    return; % Exit from the program.
end % Of first if statement
%array of break points
brkpnt = [0 50:10:80 101];
%distance between breakpoints
cnt = diff(brkpnt);
%table of grades corresponding to related marks
Grades = repelem('FDCBA', cnt);
%the result. 1  added to mark to make indices greater than 0
grade = Grades(mark + 1)
```

or you may use simple vectorized form

```
grade(mark >= 80) = 'A';
grade(mark < 80 & mark >= 70) = 'B';
grade(mark < 70 & mark >= 60) = 'C';
grade(mark < 60 & mark >= 50) = 'D';
grade(mark < 50) = 'F';
```

I compared these methos with a benchmark that its **result** is:

```
-----------repelem method---
Elapsed time is 0.00621986 seconds.
-----------bsxfun method---
Elapsed time is 0.022429 seconds.
-----------simple vectorized method---
Elapsed time is 0.0253041 seconds.
-----------for loop method---
Elapsed time is 7.7302 seconds.
```

The  benchmark : [**Online Demo**](http://rextester.com/IUY64482)

Comment: Thankyou! I used simple vectorized. How may I get grade in a cell array form. (So I can input 'grade' into a structure array). eg: [F] [C] [B] [A] [A]

Comment: I was thinking str2num maybe?

Comment: @Agnel You can use cellstr. `a = 'ABCDEF'; disp(cellstr(a.'))`