# MATLAB - Convert char to 1x5 cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, char, double, cell-array

I have 5 grades F, F, D, B, A in grade = FFDBA . I am not sure how to convert each grade to a cell array? i.e. ans= [F] [F] [D] [B] [A]. cellstr(grade) only creates a 1x1 cell array [FFDBA]. I'd like a 1x5 cell.

Comment: If this has to do with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39819571/2586922), you can generate cell array output directly; see edit to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`num2cell`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) function to convert an array to a cell, when you want to split the array into same-size parts.

```
grade = 'FFDBA';
num2cell(grade,size(grade))

ans = 
    'F'    'F'    'D'    'B'    'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

grade should be a column vector so the array should be transposed:

```
cellstr(grade.')
```